# QWidget transparency goes away when parent set

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I want to have "flying" info above my interface (like informationnal text).
I have subclassed QWidget, set the FramelessWindowHint and TranslucentBackground flags.

So I create it with my interface's widget as ctor parameter, and style (style is in a ressource QSS file and set to qApp in main) does apply to my custom widget except for background (I can put a borderbut no background-color).
But when I make my custom widget it's own parent (I leave ctor parameters empty), then I can have my background changed.

I used this technique with the exact same flyingwidget class in another project and it worked just fine. QGLWidget may be in cause (creating widget before or after QGLWidget are created causes style to be applied or not).

here's the code where I create my widget.

```
Form_coupeHighlighterInfo *highlightCoupeInfo = new Form_coupeHighlighterInfo(this); //ctor parameter that changes
highlightCoupeInfo->setObjectName(QStringLiteral("highlightCoupeInfo"));
highlightCoupeInfo->attachToRight();
highlightCoupeInfo->setFixedWidth(400);
highlightCoupeInfo->setFixedHeight(400);
highlightCoupeInfo->setRelativePos(QPoint(-10, 0));
connect(this, SIGNAL(alignToInterface(QPointF&)), highlightCoupeInfo, SLOT(alignToInterface(QPointF&)));
```

I must add that background property doesn't work like the others but I don't get what the hell is going on with him, QSS looks like magic to me on a lot of points.

I use Qt 5.2.1 / msvc2012opengl / windows 7

Comment: Ok QGLWidget is in cause, see this article http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55631-Semi-transparent-widgets-on-top-of-QGLWidget

Comment: May I suggest to self-answer your question and mark it as solved? So, the rest of the community will better see the solution.